# Как правильно в цикле проверить текста Label-ов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я задал этот вопрос в англ версии, но из-за не правильно сформулированного вопроса мне не ответили. Постараюсь хорошо сформулировать свой вопрос.

Хочу проверить текст Label-ов в цикле для игры "Игра в 15". Но моя проверка завершается не в нужный момент.

Должен проверить последовательность чисел в лейблах от 1-ого до 13-ти.
Вот код:

```
def check(self):
num = 1 # проверка текста лейбла с числом num
for row in range(4): # лейблы в форме 4х4 доски
    for column in range(4):
        if self.my_labels[row][column]['text'] == '': # если встретился лейбл текст, которого должен быть последним в доске, выходим с ф-ции
            return
        elif int(self.my_labels[row][column].cget('text')) == num: # если совпадает то увеличиваем num на единицу и продолжаем итерацию, т.е если текст первого лейбла == 1, второго == 2 и т.д до 13ти
            num += 1
            continue
        elif row == 3 and column == 0: # если дошли до позиции лейбла текст которого должен быть равен 13-ти, то проверка успешна
            # код при успешной проверки
```

а здесь код при создании самих лейблов:

```
shuffle(self.numbers) # self.numbers - список в которой хранится числа с 1-ого до 15-ти
shuffled = self.numbers.copy()
self.EL_row, self.EL_column = int(random() * 4), int(random() * 4) # позиция для одной пустой ячейки в игре
for row in range(4):
    self.my_labels[row] = []
    for column in range(4):
        if row == self.EL_row and column == self.EL_column:
            self.my_labels[row].append(Label(self.game_frame, width=8, height=4, text="", bg="black"))
            self.my_labels[row][column].grid(row=self.EL_row, column=self.EL_column, padx=2, pady=2)
            self.my_labels[row][column].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, r=row, c=column: self.move(r, c))
            continue
        self.my_labels[row].append(Label(self.game_frame, width=8, height=4, text=shuffled.pop(), bg="white", font=15,))
        self.my_labels[row][column].grid(row=row, column=column, padx=2, pady=2)
        self.my_labels[row][column].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, r=row, c=column: self.move(r, c))
```

Мой алгоритм работает не правильно. Я закомментировал код для более ясности. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Проверка завершается не на последнем элементе, а на первом же пустом, очевидно же.

Comment: мне это и надо, чтобы проверка завершалась если встретился пустой

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, так должно работать:

```
def check(self):
  # создаем последовательность из неперемешанных чисел от 1 до 15 + пустая строка в конце
  not_shuffled_values = list(str(x) for x in range(1,16)) + ['']

  # вытаскиваем значения лейблов из деки
  deck_to_check = [self.my_labels[x][y].cget('text') for x in range(4) for y in range(4)]

  # сверяем
  if deck_to_check == not_shuffled:
    return True

  return False
```

Comment: я немного изменил ф-цию предложенную вами таким образом: `not_shuffled_values = list(str(x) for x in range(1,14))` и +`if deck_to_check[:-3] == not_shuffled:`............. чтобы проверить до 13-ти. Но так не сработала.

Comment: без изменений тоже